# How can I fix Error: "No usable fontconfig configuration file found, using fallback." in a WIN10 when I try hardsub a SRT in a MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg, fonts, subtitles

I trying to burn a subtitle on video but no way to get this.
Already create a bin fonts\fonts.conf in everywhere but seems not working right.

But the same code works on another computer.

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 057def00] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.6 (SIMPLE)
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 057def00] No usable fontconfig configuration file found, using fallback.
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 057def00] Using font provider fontconfig
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 057d6e80] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.6 (SIMPLE)
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 057d6e80] No usable fontconfig configuration file found, using fallback.
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 057d6e80] Using font provider fontconfig